# shared preferences (putStringSet) or other?

Tags: android

I build a simple program (an array string with the 10 commandment), later I create another class (index to choose other activities).

I'd like save by saved preferences this array, so the user when re-start application can continue from last point.

I read that putStringSet is available only from api 11 while I'd keep compatibily also version 2.3

Is there a way to save an array string?

thanks!

Comment: you could serialize it and put that in. look for an serializer class. otherwise you could put it one by one like so: http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/05/string-arrays-and-object-arrays-in.html

Comment: @mango That's a great solution, why don't you add it as an answer?

Comment: thanks! Put it one by one, is it a good way? (my array will become over 700 entries).

Comment: 700? How are you using these? Have you considered sqlite as a more robust save solution? It will still work but Shared prefs are more for like simple user settings. Sqlite might be more efficient than loading and saving all these entries each session, depending how you're using it

Answer (score 2):

I would convert string array to regular string using for loop and use a delimiter for example "|" and save that using putString. When retrieving it back I would split the string using the same delimiter and rebuild the array.

```
private String GetString(String[] array, String delimiter)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(String s : array)
    {
        if(sb.length() > 0) { sb.append(delimiter);}
        sb.append(s);
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

private String[] GetArray(String input, String delimiter)
{
    return input.split(delimiter);
}
```

Be careful when using GetArray because String.split() assumes regular expression as delimiter so if you use character "|" you have to escape it eg. GetArray(myArray, "\\|"); Hope this helps.

Comment: mhmh...I searched a lot but I didn't found nothing... :-( how I can build this method? thanks!